# Why nested if-statement is faster than using && operator?

Tags: php, if-statement, preferences

Actually I'm wonder, why when I use multiple conditions into one `if`-statement is slower than multiple separated `if`-statement? In other word, why using `&&` is slow?

Consider this:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;
$e = 5;
```

So the execution's time of this: `0.32209205627441`

```
if ( $a == 1 && $b == 2 && $c == 3 && $d == 4 && $e == 5 ) {}
```

And this: `0.25026607513428`

```
if ( $a == 1 ){
    if ( $b == 2 ) {
        if ( $c == 3 ) {
            if ( $d == 4 ) {
                if ( $e == 5 ) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Online Benchmark](https://3v4l.org/cVT6u)

Comment: Check opcodes and see that the chained expression performs an extra cast to bool after every comparison.

Comment: @Dan your explanation seems reasonable.

Comment: " has to compare ALL the cases" --- this is wrong. Php short-circuits.

Comment: Where are you getting that execution time? Is it time spent or is it % (e.g. from the xdebug profiler analysis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious difference is that the long chained expression performs an extra cast to bool after every comparison (since the `&&` operator requires that):

```
  11    11    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~16     !0, 1
        12      > JMPZ_EX                                          ~16     ~16, ->15
        13    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~17     !1, 2
        14        BOOL                                             ~16     ~17
        15    > > JMPZ_EX                                          ~16     ~16, ->18
        16    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~18     !2, 3
        17        BOOL                                             ~16     ~18
        18    > > JMPZ_EX                                          ~16     ~16, ->21
        19    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~19     !3, 4
        20        BOOL                                             ~16     ~19
        21    > > JMPZ_EX                                          ~16     ~16, ->24
        22    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~20     !4, 5
        23        BOOL                                             ~16     ~20
        24    > > JMPZ                                                     ~16, ->25
```

vs

```
  17    42    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~30     !0, 1
        43      > JMPZ                                                     ~30, ->52
  18    44    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~31     !1, 2
        45      > JMPZ                                                     ~31, ->52
  19    46    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~32     !2, 3
        47      > JMPZ                                                     ~32, ->52
  20    48    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~33     !3, 4
        49      > JMPZ                                                     ~33, ->52
  21    50    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~34     !4, 5
        51      > JMPZ                                                     ~34, ->52
```

Apart of that the evaluation for both implementations looks pretty similar.

Comment: As a similar question, [**initialize and set it `null`** is better or **checking before initializing**](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/320ded40a73648f9741c74e10da1473b)?

Comment: @Shafizadeh 2nd: why would one initialise something they would never need